# Auto validation and check if the username is taken. ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have that class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SafeChat.Models
{
    public class UserDto
    {
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "USERNAME_TOO_SHORT")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "USERNAME_TOO_LONG")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "WRONG_EMAIL")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my CreateUserService I'm checking is username and email already taken. How can I if is username or email taken add this info to auto validation info? Maybe I should do my own validation in the CreateUserAsync method in the CreateUserService service? Thanks for all answers, have a nice day! :D.

Comment: you want to show a msg like "This user already exists" in the login form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Remote] validation attribute

Change your UserDto to :

```
 public class UserDto
    {
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "USERNAME_TOO_SHORT")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "USERNAME_TOO_LONG")]
        [Remote(action: "VerifyUserName", controller: "Users")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "WRONG_EMAIL")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a new endpoint for your validation

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult VerifyUserName(string userName)
{
    if (!_userService.VerifyUserName(userName))
    {
        return Json($"User Name {userName} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#remote-attribute)

Using a MVC template out of the box you should see something like that when the validation fail.
[image]

Comment: Ok, but it returns to me "email is taken", but doesn't add this info to auto validation error list. It is possible, to do it?

Comment: Or maybe Remote for each field individually is a good solution and will I use it?

Comment: @Szyszka947 I believe you might have some globalization on your UI or Middleware as you are using a key "USERNAME_TOO_LONG" to the other validations messages.

Comment: I'll just add that I don't use mvc but angular + api. Is this still nice solution?

Comment: @Szyszka947 From the UI perspective probably not the best, I would call the VerifyUserName direct from the UI, and keep the remote for the server-side as you already use attributes.  but that's an educated guess.

Comment: I did two own attributes which extends from ValidationAttribute class, and I configured auto validation which is look as it: https://pastebin.com/7yUivQFs Thanks for help!